# Kafka aci hangs on waiting

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-resource-manager

I am new to kafka and to azure, so go easy on me, I am trying to run `bitnami/kafka` as part of a container group

```json
"containers": [
          {
            "name": "kafka",
            "properties": {
              "image": "bitnami/kafka",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 9092,
                  "protocol": "TCP"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGB": 2
                }
              },
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER",
                  "value": "yes"
                },
                {
                  "name": "KAFKA_TLS_CLIENT_AUTH",
                  "value": "none"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
...
```

My container group has access to the internet and has vn attached and works perfectly if I remove this container, but whenever I add it, it hangs as following
[image: kafka hanging]
Tried with different kafka images, some result, any idea what am I doing wrong or how I can debug it? (logs not available at this stage afaik)

Comment: You need to look at the logs. More specifically, you're missing required variables for running Kafka